# Adding a root element to XSD from a java prog

Tags: java, dom, xsd, jaxb, sax

I have seen posts where where we can add a root element to XML, but i want to specefically add a root complex element around the incoming XSD. I see two cases here where the existing XSD root element is of named type or anonymous:

So if the xsd with named root element:

```
   <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   targetNamespace="http://a.b/c/d" elementFormDefault="qualified"> 
            <xs:element name="oldRoot" type="oldRoot"/>
```

should be transformed to :

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   targetNamespace="http://a.b/c/d" elementFormDefault="qualified"> 
 <xs:element name="newRoot">
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>  
    <xs:element name="oldRoot" type="oldRoot"/>
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

and a XSD with anonymous type:

```
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://a.b/c/d" elementFormDefault="qualified">
     <xs:element name="oldRoot">
       <xs:complexType>           
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="oldChild1">
               <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="someElement" type="xs:string"/> 
                 </xs:sequence>        
               </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
       </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
```

Should be transformed to

```
<xs:element name="newRoot">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="oldRoot"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="oldRoot">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="oldChild1">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="someElement" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I was playing around with DOM parser to help me with these edits, but can DOM parser be used for the above 2 cases ?

So can I construct the new root element and then embed the old Root element into it? is that how i can solve this or is there some other way?

the code :

```
is = new FileInputStream("/home/xyz/testing.xsd");
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document oldDoc = builder.parse(is);

Node oldRoot = oldDoc.getDocumentElement();

Document newDoc = builder.newDocument();

Element newComplexType = newDoc
.createElement("xs:complexType");
Element newSequence = newDoc.createElement("xs:sequence");
Element newElement = newDoc.createElement("xs:element");
newComplexType.setAttribute("name", "newRoot"); 


newDoc.appendChild(newComplexType);

newComplexType.appendChild(newDoc.importNode(oldRoot, true));
```

Comment: Have you attempted any Java code yet?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, have added the code, however does DOM make changes to existing XSD if i add a new root element? , i was not able to .

Comment: `<xs:element name="oldRoot"/>` is without type. It does not automatically use the type `<xs:complexType name="oldRoot">`. But otherwise **yes**: An XSD is XML, so DOM can parse, manipulate, and save it.

Comment: Did my answer helped you with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

DOM stands for Document Object Model. Using a DOM document, you are using a object containing the model (structure) of a document, you can append elements, delete elements, etc and the model (structure of the DOM object/document) will change, but that doesn't change any file contents unless you specifically write the DOM to a file.

This means that you don't need need to create two documents. You should create only a DOM document from your file, then modify the DOM (moving and creating nodes) and the write the DOM contents to a file.

```
final String XS_URI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("xsd2.xsd");
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(is); // Our DOM document
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

// Search required xs:element (old element)
XPathExpression firstElementExpr = xpath.compile("/*/*[local-name()='element'][1]");
Element element = (Element) firstElementExpr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);

// Create new elements, add them to Document Object Model
Element newElement = doc.createElementNS(XS_URI, "element");
Element newComplexType = doc.createElementNS(XS_URI, "complexType");
Element newSequence = doc.createElementNS(XS_URI, "sequence");
doc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(newElement); // new xs:element inside xs:schema
newElement.appendChild(newComplexType); // new xs:complexType inside new xs:element
newComplexType.appendChild(newSequence); // new xs:sequence inside new xs:complexType
newElement.setAttribute("name", "newRoot"); // Add name attribute
// Note that the order of these operations can be changed, the resulting DOM should be the same.


newSequence.appendChild(element); // The old element is moved inside the new xs:sequence
if (element.hasAttribute("type")) {
    // Everything is done (the old element have been moved inside the new sequence)
} else {
    NodeList childNodes = element.getChildNodes(); // Nodes inside old element. This also contains comments (<!-- -->), text nodes, etc
    for (int i=0; i<childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
        /*
         * We iterate nodes till we found xs:complexType
         * Then we move xs:comlpexType inside xs:schema and add the required name attribute
         */
        if ("complexType".equals(childNodes.item(i).getLocalName())) {
            Element complexType = (Element) childNodes.item(i);
            complexType.setAttribute("name", "oldRoot"); // Maybe in your specific case, attribute value should be element.getAttribute("name")??
            doc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(complexType);
        }
    }
}
saveDocument(doc, "newXSD.xsd");
```

Finally you can write the DOM document to a file, or as a String as you can see in many Stackoverflow questions.